# Simple blog written in java for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blogs

My website is deployed on google app engine. Now, I'd like to create a new page/section in my web site to add a blog.

I'm wondering if you know a simple blog written in java that could be deployed on Google app engine? I'm not afraid to edit this code...

Many Thanks!

P.S : my subject is not a duplicate. The other solutions are for python and their assume that your deploy ONLY the blog on your google server.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.gaecupboard.com/tag/java/blogs?category=Libraries) for some java blog projects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blogging System which runs on the Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804368/blogging-system-which-runs-on-the-google-app-engine)

Comment: there are lots of questions about blog systems on java for app engine.  the question I cited as the dupe is just one of several.  bloog and bloggart seem to be some of the popular choices.

Answer (score 0):

[B3log Solo](https://github.com/b3log/b3log-solo) is a very active open source blog system based on GAE/Java, while currently multi-languages are not so well except Chinese-Simple. If you are interested in it, please loop here. I am very welcomed to help with how to config to run it in GAE.